# Views PDF : class not found

Tags: drupal-views

Probably a Drupal issue, but you never know :

I am running Drupal 7.56 / Civi 4.7.20

I have been using Views extensively for some months now. I want now to create custom pdf pages from some Views.

I have installed jQuery_update, then Views PDF Display Module, then copied fpdi and tcpdf libraries into the Libraries folder (via FTP).

Now, when I want to add a PDF Page to a View, I get the following error message : 
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'sites/all/libraries/fpdi/fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php' (include_path='/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/nz.co.fuzion.cmcic-master/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/org.civicrm.sms.twilio/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/packages/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/default/fpdf:.:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules in /home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/views_pdf/views_pdf_template.php on line 22

I suspect that this is due to a bad installation (btw, the fdpi library contains no fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php), but find no clear and up-to-date installation tutorial.

I am not a programmer (just able to edit and ftp a file if necessary)

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I went back to fpdi-1.6.2, and the error disappeared (the internal fpdi folder content has completely changed between the two versions).